# Multiple processes reading&deleting files in the same directory

Tags: python, bash, shell, race-condition

I have a directory with thousands of files and each of them has to be processed (by a python script) and subsequently deleted.

I would like to write a bash script that reads a file in the folder, processes it, deletes it and moves onto another file - the order is not important. There will be n running instances of this bash script (e.g. 10), all operating on the same directory. They quit when there are no more files left in the directory.

I think this creates a race condition. Could you give me an advice (or a code snippet) how to make sure that no two bash scripts operate on the same file?

Or do you think I should rather implement multithreading in Python (instead of running n different bash scripts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact the file renames (on the same file system) are atomic on Unix systems, i.e. a file was either renamed or not. For the sake of clarity, let us assume that all files you need to process have name beginning with A (you can avoid this by having some separate folder for the files you are processing right now).

Then, your bash script iterates over the files, tries to rename them, calls the python script (I call it `process` here) if it succeeds and else just continues. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in A*; do
    pfile=processing.$file
    if mv "$file" "$pfile"; then
       process "$pfile"
       rm "$pfile"
    fi
done
```

This snippet uses the fact that `mv` returns a 0 exit code if it was able to move the file and a non-zero exit code else.

Answer (score 1):

The only sure way that no two scripts will act on the same file at the same time is to employ some kind of file locking mechanism. A simple way to do this could be to rename the file before beginning work, by appending some known string to the file name. The work is then done and the file deleted. Each script tests the file name before doing anything, and moves on if it is 'special'.

A more complex approach would be to maintain a temporary file containing the names of files that are 'in process'. This file would obviously need to be removed once everything is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is a consumer producer pattern. I think this solution is the right way to start:

[producer/consumer problem with python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914821/producer-consumer-problem-with-python-multiprocessing)